# React Native - a fresh new app shows only a black screen. How to debug?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am starting exploring building mobile apps with React Native and running, even after going through many tutorials, into repeating issues.

I generated a new app via the `react-native init MyApp` command - I noticed that in the `App.js` file were included these styles definitions:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

However, if I decided to only use

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Header />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I only get back a black screen in the simulator - to "see" something, I need to add the style definition, as:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Header />
</View>
```

How do I avoid always specifying the style definition for `<View>`? Is the default setup that the background of the screen is black or am I overlooking something?

So far - the development is quite confusing and difficult, I spent basically the whole afternoon restarting the iOS app (hot reloading doesn't always work) to see new code changes in the app instead of building some new functionality.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong (like using the wrong development tools)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the `AppDelegate.m` you will see that the the rootView has its color set as follows

```
rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

This sets the default color to black, you can change it to whatever you want.

However it won't affect anything that you do on Android so it would be best just to set your backgroundColor in the View.

Comment: Thanks, I found it - I remember I was playing with RN last summer and lots of things has changed since then... Might I ask you for some tips for debugging? So far it's more like a black box and I am spending a lot of time turning off & on the app (= spending more time and restarting the app than actually building any functionality).

Comment: I find that hot-reloading is only useful if you are not editing state. Otherwise you need to reload. There are two ways to reload `CMD+R` or `react-native run-ios`. I usually use `CMD+R` to refresh the bundle on the device. If I have made changes to native code, installed new dependencies, then using `react-native run-ios` to update the bundle is the best option, then I can go back to using `CMD+R`

Comment: You should also look to use `react-native-debugger` this is better than using the window in the Chrome browser. https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger

Comment: Thank you, will check it out.

Comment: The nice thing about `react-native-debugger` is that if you move on to using `redux` with a few minor tweaks to your middleware you can see your redux state and actions in the debugger.